# Is there a way to bind 2 (or more) WPF items to a single property in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

My class contains an `address` property (string type), but my WPF window contains a few text boxes for the address (house number, street name and optional second line of address - the town and postcode do have separate fields in the class).
I would like to get them all into the single `address` string in the class, separated by commas (eg. "43, Whitefield Road, Princesshire"). Is there a way to do so by binding, or only manually in the code?

[image]

Comment: You're much better off having your model reflect how you need these bound. You could use a separate class that exposes each of these as properties, then it could do the translation of combining the properties into a single string.

Comment: I agree. You can use a converter as shown below but this is really something that you should be able to unit test without a view getting in the way. If you find yourself having to use converters to implement anything but the most basic logic then it's usually a good sign that the model you're binding to (e.g. the view model in the case of mvvm) isn't doing its job properly.

Answer (score 1):

Bind all the fields to the Address property on your class, then use a value converter to determine which components of the address are applicable. In the converter have a property allowing you to determine which substring to manipulate:

```
public class AddressSeparatorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    ///<summary>
    /// Index of the substring element of the address to be manipulated (read/edited).
    ///</summary>
    public int SubStringIdx { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Then when you perform the conversion, you simply split the string using the , delimiter and return the substring as specified by the SubStringIdx:

```
address.Split(',')[SubStringIdx]
```

As you're binding to an editable control, you will need to make sure you provide implementations for both [IValueConverter.Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convert(v=vs.110).aspx) and [IValueConverter.ConvertBack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.convertback(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

To take this one step further, you could provide different converter definitions in your Converters.xaml file to handle the various subcomponents of address:

```
<converters:AddressSeparatorConverter x:Key="AddressToHouseNumberConverter" SubStringIdx="0"/>
<converters:AddressSeparatorConverter x:Key="AddressToStreetNameConverter" SubStringIdx="1"/>
...
```

Then when binding to your control you would call the appropriate converter by its key:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Address, Converter={StaticResource AddressToStreetNameConverter}}"/>
```

I don't have access to an IDE right now so please accept the code snippets may not be 100% right but you should get the gist of it.

Comment: To be honest although I've proposed a solution to having address as a single field, as it's really a composite field it would be much cleaner to split it out into separate properties.

Answer (score 0):

use MultiBinding:

The syntax for address textbox text binding would be:

```
<TextBox Width="100" >
        <TextBox.Text>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource YourAddressConverter}">
                //order below bindings as you want them in the array passed to converter
                <Binding ElementName="Houseblock" Path="Text"/>
                <Binding ElementName="streetblock" Path="Text"/>
                 .......................
                <Binding ElementName="townblock" Path="Text"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBox.Text>
    </TextBox>
```

where using **elementbinding** the text of other textboxes is binded to finaltextbox(address) and **YourAddressConverter** is a converter that will contain the login of concatenation of address components as below in it's convert method.

```
public class YourAddressConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return values[0].ToString() + " " + values[1].ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

It's the simplest and best solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you create an `Address` object with separate fields for the house number, street name, post code etc. you can bind to each individually.

If you want to print out the whole address you then create a read only property which combines the various parts of the address into a single string:

```
public string SingleLineFormat
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}, {2}, {3}", this.Number, this.Street, this.Town, this.PostCode);
    }
}
```

You could even have different versions that return the string formatted across several lines or with different combinations of the address as required.

```
public string MultiLineFormat
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}{4} {2}{4} {3}", this.Number, this.Street, this.Town, this.PostCode, Environment.NewLine);
    }
}
```